# Drawing doubles in dominoes

Tags: probability

When you are playing [dominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) the person with the highest double starts. Now, I was playing dominoes with my wife last night and I commented that it is odd that someone almost always gets a double because the odds are against it. My wife pointed out that I was wrong. However, we couldn't work out what the probability of drawing a hand with a double in it is. So that is my question.

> You are playing dominoes with your (real or imaginary) wife. There are 28 dominoes, 7 of which are doubles. Each hand contains 7 dominoes. What is the probability of drawing a hand containing at least one double in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ${28 \choose 7}=1184040$ total hands.  There are ${21 \choose 7}=116280$ that don't have a double.  The odds that a single hand does not have a double are $\frac {323}{3289}$ or just under $10\%$.  If you want neither player to have a double, it goes down to $\frac {\frac 12 {21 \choose 7}{14 \choose 7}}{\frac 12 {28 \choose 7}{21 \choose 7}}=\frac 1{345}$, very low indeed.

Comment: Thanks - I think my mind gave up and went to bed on Sunday and is yet to get up.

Comment: This isn't quite right. There are not $28\choose 14$ ways of picking 2 hands, but ${28\choose 7}+{21\choose 7}$, so it should be $\frac{{28\choose 7}+{21\choose 7}-{21\choose 7}-{14\choose 7}}{{28\choose 7}+{21\choose 7}}=\frac{{28\choose 7}-{14\choose 7}}{{28\choose 7}+{21\choose 7}}$. (Which is the same probability that one hand doesn't have a double.) No?

Comment: @user1729:  It doesn't matter.  Looking again, the number of ways of picking two hands is $\frac 12 {28 choose 7}{21 \choose 7}$  You multiply because each second hand can go with many first hands.  The factor $\frac 12$ comes from swapping the hands.  It turns out the final answer is the same, because you might as well pile the two hands together and look for a double within them.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks.